# generate 2d array with random values TypeScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, dimensions

I try to generate 2d numeric array on typescript
Initialization:

```
weight: number[][] = [];
```

And generation values:

```
private generateWeights(): void {
    this.weight = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      this.weight[i] = [];
      for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        this.weight[i][j] = Math.random() * 2;
      }
    }
    console.log('this.weight: ', this.weight);
  }
```

But on console I get some static values like picture:
[image]

When I try to print row of 2d array i get strange console.log:

[image]

Comment: the loop logic looks good, ideally it should give different values. Did you try multiple times?

Comment: yes, after each attempt I get the same values. Whe I use console.(randomValue) I see write value but array allways get this values. I have no idea why

Comment: The console prints out `-0` which shouldn't be possible unless the code you provided isn't complete. What else is editing the `weights`?

Comment: Nothing. It is full code for geterate weights Array

Comment: You should use another browser to run the file... Because of the way the console is

Comment: @a.mola  So, if on next lines weights will be changed, how I can wait this generate before change weights?

Comment: I saw the answer you commented, your `generateWeights` function isn't meant to be asynchronous. So I don't know why you have to wait, unless wherever you're calling the function from is asynchronous

Comment: Can you show me where you're calling the function from

Comment: @a.mola yes,  add this code to stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-krfzno?file=src%2Fapp%2Fservices%2Flearning.service.ts

Comment: I've looked at the code, and yes you where running the code asynchronously with Promises... I don't think that's necessary based on the code i've seen, so I changed the code back synchronously... Test it out... ensure you see the changes first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I put together [a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=8&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAcwKZlQJwIZVQdVRmQAsoBnACkzgHdyAuRMEAWwCMsAaRCOAG0bM2nTAEomLDlgDaAXXmIA3gChEiTKighMSAIKYcATwB0wGq0pLE-dMigkmNeogC+Yk62wAHSpTGIALwAfGrqiAbGZhZWNnYOTHyCbh5evv5BwYgAsrgkJjhgACZwlgEAVIgATGJhYgDcKq4qKnxg5AKoJvxwyJRoGDh4hMRkVADsPACsYg0qQA) with one approach you could use which works well at least when running on its own. Sorry without knowing what the rest of your code looks like it's not easy to see why you are encountering a problem.

```
function generateWeights(rows: number, cols: number): number[][] {
  return Array.from({ length: rows }).map(() =>
    Array.from({ length: cols }).map(() => Math.random() * 2)
  );
}

//example invocation
console.log(JSON.stringify(generateWeights(7, 5), null, "  "));
```

The example invocation produces...

```
[
  [
    1.9665769596410398,
    0.32225623317750873,
    1.979382321105576,
    1.3400841950364906,
    0.0333557898363388
  ],
  [
    0.523308974899896,
    0.519975189295653,
    0.14464403965018624,
    0.7799904829432234,
    0.7748489552011621
  ],
  [
    1.2637757372417209,
    0.9375011277636429,
    0.46157500412620367,
    0.7470383909903693,
    0.45140251266154596
  ],
  [
    0.9576573640144601,
    0.7096653222305775,
    1.7104635189269257,
    0.16415705266079472,
    0.38377189535968403
  ],
  [
    0.04732945754404572,
    0.7050064626827024,
    0.8450634927445284,
    0.12460094121473508,
    0.6501398542245567
  ],
  [
    0.5087564269629801,
    0.8193243695084456,
    1.4786471319572896,
    0.35962390487698004,
    1.5651415242853055
  ],
  [
    0.31416888386760533,
    1.088122706073758,
    0.9604222417055066,
    0.6956030508790003,
    1.6623759187576028
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thanks, The problem was that console.log works with a some small delay and the array had time to be overwritten before it will be print in the console